Closing USB serial port hangs any application of VirtualBox
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox (Ubuntu 24.04 as host if that matters) and I have an ESP32-S3 board connected on USB port. Guest additions installed. Acquiring the device inside the VM it correcly appears as /dev/ttyACM0:
[  121.563256] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
[  122.069667] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=303a, idProduct=1001, bcdDevice= 1.01
[  122.069673] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  122.069676] usb 1-2: Product: USB JTAG/serial debug unit
[  122.069678] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Espressif
[  122.069679] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 24:58:7C:F4:95:E4
[  122.086870] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  122.086913] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[  122.086915] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters

Using any application, like Cutecom or Visual Studio Code I can successfully open the serial port and exchange data. But when I close it the application hangs, I cannot use it anymore or close it.
Furthermore, the VM machine is still functional but I cannot shutdown. It simply ignores the sudo halt command or even from Gnome. I cannot even turn off the machine from VirtualBox interface, I have to kill the host process.
The only thing I was able to do is inspecting the dmesg after closing the serial port:
[  266.942786] ohci-pci 0000:00:06.0: frame counter not updating; disabled
[  266.942799] ohci-pci 0000:00:06.0: HC died; cleaning up

and from a search on the web it seems related to the USB CDC but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Do you have guest additions installed?

@kyrlon yes I have

OK. Just sanity check. What version of VBox are you on? And are you attaching the usb device to vm every time from Vbox or just inside the VM?

I tried with 7.0.20 and now I'm with 7.0.16. When I run the VM I attach the USB device from VirtualBox menu. Then inside the VM I open the port. When I close it the malfunction happens.

I found a solution to this.
Shut down the virtual machine
Go to settings->USB and select the USB3.0 (xHCI) Controller instead of the USB 2.0 controller.
Everything worked for me after that
